# Github branching strategy

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have a git repo which has multiple branches and different versions on the product. I am need to come up with a strategy where I can implement a CI pipeline.

Currently, there are many branches which have never been merged and the master is not updated as well.

There will be development going for multiple versions of the code. Any suggestions on which strategy can be implemented.

I am considering having a fork of the different versions because the code base is very different and would never be merged.

In essence each branch is a different product. Forking it would be best in my opinion.

Comment: This question is touching upon both "too broad" and "primarily opinion-based" so unfortunately, I will have to vote to close it. What you need is to have a good *discussion* about how you intend to move forward, there is no single acceptable answer to this unfortunately.

Comment: My advice would be to come up with a few different ways of handling this, and then discuss and try to uncover pros and cons of each method, then compare. Likely you will not find one that is perfect but will have to compromise.

Comment: Have you looked at [git flow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)?

Comment: Yes I have looked at git flow but the issue here is that I have different versions of the product and they are too different to be merged hence I think I need to fork then as per the versions

Comment: And this is why I feel this question is not a good fit for a Q&A site such as Stack Overflow, whatever people might suggest you will always come up with "yes, but ...", so you need a place to discuss this instead. Have you tried our chat rooms? You'll find them on the Stack Exchange menu top right.

Comment: Thanks I agree with you. I will try out the chat rooms. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.